# how to switch between processes in pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I am debugging a Python application, that makes use of os.fork() at some point.
After evaluating the function PDB remains in the parent process (as I can see from the value returned from the function).

How do I switch between child and parent process in PDB?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it automatically gets switched at some point (probably I/O).
If you want to force it though, you should call time.sleep().

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with pdb.  Your best bet will be to start your pdb session (using pdb.set_trace()) inside the child process after the fork.